# Find links with certain class and add javascript to link

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

Trying to do two things:

1) Look for links that have the class "download" attached.
2) If so, add some Google Event Tracking code to the link

As a means of testing, here's what I have thus far:

```
​<a href="#" class="download">Test</a>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
if ($(a).is('.download')){
        $(a).append('onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Podcasts', 'Download', 'Title']);"');
        }
}
```

Can't seem to get this to work, althought I think (*hope*) I have the right idea.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
   $('a.download').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var $a = $(this);
      // $a is the anchor that was clicked. you can access attributes or its text to populate the _gaq.push call below.  e.g. var text = $a.text();
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Podcasts', 'Download', $a.attr('href')]);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the class selector instead of `is()`. Also your code will give js error because `a` is not defined as there are not quotes around it so it will be treated as a variable which is not defined.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('a.download').click(function(){
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Podcasts', 'Download', this.href]);
         return false;
    });
});
```

Class selector reference - http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

As a side note `is()` checks the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

Comment: Great.  My problem with this, though, is that I have several links on a page, and each has a different title.  I guess I'd need to add more to this in order to pull in the media files to which these <a>'s are linking.

Comment: You can change the selector as per your need so that it selects only the required anchor elements on the page. And in the question you have mentioned a class not the title.

Comment: Is there a way to change the 'Title' portion once the link is clicked so that it includes the "href" of the link?  Maybe something like adding a var title = $('a.download').attr('href'); in there?

Comment: @ndisdabest - Check my edited answer `this.href` will give you the `href` value of the anchor you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.download').on('click', function(){
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Podcasts', 'Download', 'Title']);
        });
```

This should do what you want.